# CakePHP 2 - Converting Userinputs to lowercase

Tags: php, cakephp, view, controller, lowercase

I have written in CakePHP 2.3, for my project an user management. Everything works fine. 
But now I would like to have a registration function in which the user can create themselves.
Even that's not the problem. But Cake is to set the user name itself.

I have 2 fields. "first_name" and "last_name"
Well I thought I convert both fields with the PHP function "strtolower" to lowercase, put a point between them and the result gives the user name. For example "john.doe"

My only question is, how do I get through this.

I think it will not help me when i put the php function into my "register" view, because the fields are empty and so the function can not do his job.

How do I get it back so that the input is formatted by the user as in my example, and is stored in a separate database field

Who can help me in this regard?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller before you save the user.

for example something like this:

```
public function register() {

  // ...

  $username = strtolower($this->request->data['User']['first_name'] . "." . $this->request->data['User']['last_name']);
  $this->request->data['User']['username'] = $username;

  if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
    // ...
  } 
}
```

Also if you're having trouble understanding, how Cake or the MVC Design Pattern works, do you a favor and read the CakePHP [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html).

Comment: It's best to perform this kind of operations inside the `beforeValidate()` callback inside the model. That guarantees that the user-input will *always* be formatted. Read the manual here: [Model::beforeValidate()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforevalidate)